# are there any other properties like sub-modularity which can help compute the maximization problem of a set function

Tags: graph-theory, approximation-theory, network

Now I have a set function $f$ (it's monotone), which inputs a node set $S$, and output a real value $r=f(S)$. And I want to compute 
$$
\max_{S,|S|\leq k}f(S).
$$
where k is given number. And I know this problem is NP-hard now.

If f(S) is a submodularity function, then we can use greedy algorithm to compute it with a good approximation in polynomial time. But unfortunately, f(S) is not a submodularity function. So I want to ask is there any other property like sub-modularity to help compute this problem?